# Unzip specific files from multiple zip files

Tags: shell, find, zip

I'm new to Unix and am trying to extract specific pattern filename from the multiple zip files. I'm using `find` to find the zip files, and then trying to extract files having the filename CTL in the zip file, `a*b*zip`.

```
$ unzip -jn 'find $source_dir -mtime -$st_d -daystart -iname "a*zip"' \
    *CTL* -d $target_dir`
```

Other than this I tried using:

```
$ find -type f -newermt $start_date \! -newermt $end_date -name "a*zip" \
    | while read filename; do unzip -d $target_dir; done;`
```

but this is extracting all the files, but I'm looking for only those files, which have filename *CTL*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do that using `find -exec` alone.

```
find . -type f -name '*.zip' -exec unzip {}  '*CTL*' -d "$target_dir" \;
```

**Explanation:** `-exec` will execute the following command on each file found where `{}` is substituted for the filename. The command must be terminated by `;`. Use `\;` at the end (';' escaped with `\`) to avoid your shell from interpreting the `;` for its own as a termination for `find`, instead it is passed to `find` as regular text.

Also, notice that it is a good practice to enclose file patterns in quotes when they are passed as arguments, i.e. `'*CTL*'` as opposed to just `*CTL*`. When doing so, you avoid letting your shell expand the filenames. For example, suppose in this case one of your zip files has CTL in its filename (say `abcCTL.zip`). If you use just `*CTL*` for the pattern, the shell will expand it and instead of passing a pattern to `unzip`, it will instead pass the filename `abcCTL.zip`, which is clearly not what you want.

Comment: This doesn't sound right. Notice that `find .` searches in the current directory. If you run it from `/` it is going to search everywhere, including the `/target_dir`. Try to give a specific directory to look into `find /ddw_projs/ddw/tst/data/` for example.